# Where is Firebase authentication API listed and documented?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

From the website,  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

I can piece together some functions, but is there a comprehensive list of all functions, with documentation?

Using Node.js  from firebase cloud functions

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're accessing Firebase Auth from a Cloud Function, you're likely using the Firebase Admin SDK. The guide for that specific combination is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/

You can find a list of all Auth-related methods in the Node.js Admin SDK here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth